# How to set a wildcard for connect-src content security policy in html?

Tags: html, content-security-policy

In html I have this

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src 'self'; connect-src file: https://data.global ws://localhost:* http://localhost:*; img-src http://localhost:* file: blob: data:; font-src file: http://localhost:*; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
/>
```

But for the `connect-src` I have many domains I want whitelisted. Sometimes they are created frequently so I don't want to keep updating this each time. Is there a way I can just allow all domains? I could potentially remove `connect-src` but then the `default-src` will kick in and break it.

Comment: maybe try `*` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use * to match any HTTP/HTTPS source as well as the current origin's scheme. Use https to match any HTTPS source.